# Editing entity property (title) with ECK and editablefields

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using [Entity Construction Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) and [Editablefields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields).  When configuring the "Manage Display" of a bundle, the properties (specifically, "title") do not have the option of "editable".
[image]

Is there a way to make the entity property fields editable as well?  I'm considering doing a dummy field that updates the entity title on save.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module to replace the default title field.

Comment: Hmm. This module converts to a field api but there may be a bug as it does not work with editablefields (i.e. it doesn't update the title).